# div tag increment using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var i = 1;

function copy() {
  var content = document.getElementById("div0").innerHTML;
  var replace = content.replace('<a onclick="copy()"><img src="<?=$this->webroot;?>img/approve.png"></a>', '');
  var replace = replace.replace(/0/g, i);
  $("<div id='div" + i + "'>" + replace + "<a onclick='removediv(" + i + ")'><img src='<?=$this->webroot;?>img/delete.png'></a></div>").appendTo("#divcontent");
  i++;
}

function removediv(val) {
  $("#divcontent").children("#div" + val).remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divcontentouter">
  <div id="divcontent">
    <div id='div0'>
      <a onclick="copy()">Click Here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did for single increment but I want another set like this inside for child div. If I click `Click Here` it gets incremented, then I want another set of div inside this for increment. I tried it but could not get it.

Comment: You really should standardise on jQuery here

Comment: can you use jQuery also?

Comment: ok, but i want it to be worked anyhow...

Comment: You mean you want to have a click here inside the dynamic created div, from there you should append new block right?

Comment: your current code is also working in that manner?

Comment: hmm yes, like parent and child div set... but i want both to be incremental...

Comment: I Want same div set inside these div with different id name and it has to be incremental.

Comment: @BenedictRuban refer my answer there no id required you can get element using $(this) and with reference to parent easily in jquery

Comment: instead of ul and li give me div and i want text box in both parent and child so that i can save the value in database...like for one parent 2 or more child value..and another parent 2 or more child value...

Comment: @BenedictRuban I made it as div, take my updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try below, I made it in ul li, to show it append into child div if you want you can change it to div also:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Stack HTML</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="divcontentouter">
    <div id="divcontent">
      <div id='div0'>
        <a class="click">Click Here</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(document).on('click', '.click', function() {
        var htmlElement = '<div><span><a class="child-click">Click Here </a><a class="remove"><img src="<?=$this->webroot;?>img/approve.png"></a></span></div>';

        $('#divcontent').append(htmlElement);
      });

      $(document).on('click', 'a.child-click', function() {
        var htmlElement = '<div><span>Click Here <a class="remove"><img src="<?=$this->webroot;?>img/approve.png"></a></span></div>';
        $(this).closest('div').append(htmlElement);
      });

      $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        var currentElement = $(this).closest('div').remove();
      });


    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```